# Eye contact culture in Vietnam

Tags: vietnam, culture

In Vietnam, unlike in Thailand, it's noticeable that people typically refrain from smiling during public eye contact, such as when walking on the streets. In Australia, there is a distinct practice of actively avoiding eye contact; however, when it occurs, there's often a subtle exchange of smiles. This dynamic appears different in Vietnam. As a tourist, one experiences locals looking at them, and in turn, the tourist observes both the people and the surrounding environment. What cultural norms influence the dynamics of eye contact and smiling in this context?